# In a Angular reactive form I'm unable to get a file using input type of file. The onchange event only return "isTrusted":true

Tags: angular

Using the following input:

```html
<input #fileUploadInput type="file" id="fileUpload" (click)="fileUploadInput.value = null" name="fileUpload" (change)="fileSelected($event)" />
```

The change `$event` value only returns `{"isTrusted":true}` when I select a file.

The change event handler is simply:

```js
fileSelected(fileSelected: any) {
  console.log('FILE1 ' + JSON.stringify(fileSelected));
  console.log('FILE2 ' + JSON.stringify(fileSelected.target.files));
}
```

Returned in console log is...

```
{FILE1 "isTrusted":true} and 
{FILE2 "0":{}}
```

Any suggestions as to why I don't have any file objects returned from the event?

Comment: You can’t stringify a file. Stop using that

Comment: That might explain it then! Thanks bryan60